# How do you do list slicing equivalent to python in Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby, list, porting, slice

I am tryiing to port some python code to ruby, and I am doing pretty well, using equivelent ruby functions, even removing / altering some to use ruby features more.
However at a core point I need to get slices from an array 
in python the following works fine:

```
output=["Apple","Orange","Pear"]
team_slices=[(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)]
for start,end in team_slices:
    print output[start:end]
```

Will output as expected:

```
['Apple']
['Orange']
['Pear']
```

Whereas the ruby code:

```
output=["Apple","Orange","Pear"]
team_slices=[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
team_slices.each do |start,ending|
    print output[start..ending]
end
```

Will output:

```
["Apple","Orange"]
["Orange","Pear"]
["Pear"]
```

Is there any way to do the slicing more equivalent to python? I know I am likely missing somethign simple here

Comment: "in python the following works fine" - I am seeing an error with the Python code, `output[start:end]` is a list and it is being added to a string (causes TypeError).

Comment: Are you sure that code is working at all? You can't have `end` as a variable name in Ruby.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall It was example code, to show my problem, Messed up on that

Comment: @F.J My mistake, again was quick example code to try and show the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like python's ranges exclude the end value, so just use the `...` variant in ruby:

```
output=["Apple","Orange","Pear"]
team_slices=[[0,1],[1,2],[2,3]]
team_slices.each do |start, last|
  print output[start...last]
end
```

PS: In ruby you should use 2 spaces for indentation, if you want to stick to conventions ;)

EDIT| Had to rename `end` to `last` due to ruby using it as a syntactical keyword.

Comment: I do use two spaces, I was unsure what to do with the weird 4 spaces thing here.

Comment: Just made an edit about the variable name `end` ;) Just tripped me up when tested the code.

Comment: @nekosune, everything must be indented at least four spaces to get the code formatting, but after that you can indent however you want, the easiest way is to format it how you want it without any indentation, select it all, then click the `{ }` button to [format it as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/155356).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall aren't the parameters offset and length when you do that?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I tried that first of all, and yeah, instead of a slice it was giving me `last` entires after `start`

Comment: @d11wtq Yea my fault, should've looked more closely at my quick example test.